# Android - do an overscroll glow effect immediately

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overscroll

I am currently using RecyclerView and LinearLayoutManager under v7 support and building under min sdk version 15.

I would like to do an overscroll glow effect immediately on the RecyclerView (manually calling a function instead of listening events) if a new item is inserted into the adapter, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

override onTouchEvent and draw a EdgeEffect by yourself.copy the EdgeEffect from android 5.0.there is a api called setColor()